# Existing property return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, undefined

I started the implementation of a RESTful API usin node.js, express, and mongodb. Everything went well until now, I've a route to authenticate an user as follow:

```
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        nickname: req.body.nickname
    }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'
            });
        } else if (user) {
            console.log(user);
            console.log(user.nickname);
            console.log(user.email);
            console.log(user.password);
            console.log(user.sexe);

            if (user.password != req.body.password) {
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'
                });
            } else {
                var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('salt'), {
                    expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
                });

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    token: token
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The user is retrieved, and loged in the console as follow:

```
{ sexe: 'H',
  email: 'MrPanda@gmail.com',
  password: 'bambou',
  nickname: 'MrPanda',
  _id: 56cb703e7aef3f83c7dac0a7 }
```

which is perfect, but then, the three following consol.log return the three following lines:

```
MrPanda
MrPanda@gmail.com
undefined
H
```

I see absolutely no reason why the password is undefined at this point, I tried to change the attribute name to 'mdp', same issue... Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Try to copy user.password to new variable and log it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `mongoose` it does **not** return a plain JSON object. It is actually a special `mongoose` object and may not function how you expect.

You have two options:

1. Convert the `mongoose` object to a `JSON` object.

   - Add `{lean: true}` to the `Users` options parameter.
   - **OR** `JSON.stringify(user)`
   - **OR** `user.toJSON()`
2. Use the proper `get()` and `set()` methods (which you should be doing anyways).

   - `user.get('password')`
   - `user.get('email')`
   - `user.get('name')`

Try that and let me know if it doesn't work still.

Comment: Thanks, was working on it for hours, but how come that I can get all the values, except for one? (which was an image URL)